# Windows Phone 8 Message Box issue

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

Procedure:
When a MessageBox.Show in the screen, User Lock his phone or press start button and then come back to the app

When an above procedure is followed, you will never see a messagebox which was appeared before you start the above procedure, instead the phone will select the default value which is OK even in OK Cancel options. What would be the case and how would I solve it?

Comment: try this `VisualTreeHelper.GetOpenPopups();` while reactivating your app. this may helps you

Comment: where should i copy this? AND this is MessageBox.Show, does it work?

Comment: @MohamedThaufeeq - if you're proposing an answer, please do so as an *answer* and not as a *comment*.

Comment: NO it is not an answer, I'm still Looking for it

Comment: @DavidMakogon I'm just giving him a suggestion, if he asks the code for it, I'll definitely give code as an answer. Am I right ?

Comment: Ok fair enough. Just wanted to make sure it could be upvoted properly. Been seeing a swarm of answers-as-comments lately - must be the weather...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think only way to avoid this issue is create your own pop up view as a message box.

Answer (score 1):

MessageBox supressess the Main App thread while opening, and when you press lock screen button the app, and every active thread goes in background. The main active app thread gets activated and the internally generated messagebox thread donot.

VisualTreeHelper.GetOpenPopups(); is the way you can check for all open popups. but the best and the most consistent solution is to use custom popups, messageboxes made in xaml. they never come up as seperate threads blocking the main UI thread.

A custom user control like this could help

```
 <Border Name="bdrLeave" Visibility="Collapsed">
            <Border.Background>
                <ImageBrush Stretch="Fill" ImageSource="/Images/LoderBackground.png"/>
            </Border.Background>
            <StackPanel>
                <StackPanel>
                    <StackPanel.Background>
                        <ImageBrush Stretch="Fill" ImageSource="/Images/Backgrounds/Main_BG.jpg"/>
                    </StackPanel.Background>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Right">
                    <TextBlock Text="Heading" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Foreground="#FF001C68" FontWeight="Bold" Margin="0,20,150,0"/>
                        <Button content="Close"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                        <TextBlock Text="Message" TextWrapping="Wrap" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Foreground="#FF001C68" Margin="0,20,0,0"/>
                    <StackPanel Margin="0,20,0,20" Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
                        <Button  Content="Content" Width="130"/>
                        <Button Content="Content" width "130"/>

                    </StackPanel>
                </StackPanel>

            </StackPanel>
        </Border>
```

Comment: COuld You give me an example of how to create custom messageboxes from xaml..?

Comment: I am updating my answer here

Comment: Yeah Thanks. Forgive me for my ignorance, but I have a lot of doubts for how you make these user controls events and how you are going to link them with the page that calls this user control, (In messageBox we get an event, if he press ok do this, if he press cancel, don't do or whatever).

Comment: you would need to access the user control in  c#, parsing its respective children and declare the events thereby. but if the pages are less then apart from making a uercontrol declare this messagebox in each page's .xaml, thats a bit convinient option.

Comment: When I declare this .xaml user control. isn't it a huge object? cause there would be memory problems in later. And also.. how to extract the return value of button event in message box to main page?

Comment: yes that's what, declare it on single pages where you need it, that would be easy, editable according to the needs and friendly, forget making it as a user control :)

Comment: So it will mostly come back to custommessagebox object. But Messagebox provide inablity access control in the page until answer given to the messagebox and also nothing proceeds untill messagebox disappears. but i assume these custom boxes would not be able to do that, is it true or not?

Comment: no, you can put this box inside the layoutroot grid but outside the contentpanel grid, and when the messagebox appears  set contentpanel ishittestvisible to false, or collapse its visibility

Comment: @gayan1991 if u need code for what you have asked for, tel me. will give with example

Comment: If you can Provide That would Be lot better, Thanks